# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list var x = $("input[name="+value+'[]'"]")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error on this. i don't know what happen here.

```
enter code here
 $(".addCategory").on('click',function(){ 
        var value= $(".getvalue").val();
        var x = $("input[name="+value+'[]'"]")
        $(x).each(function(key,val){
        if($(val).val().length<=0)
        {
           alert ("Please fill all the fileds");

        }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem with quotes

```
   var x = $("input[name='" + value + "[]']")
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem was with your quotes:
replace with following code

```
    $(".addCategory").on('click',function(){ 
            var value= $(".getvalue").val();
            var x = $("input[name='"+value+"[]']") // add proper quotes
            $(x).each(function(key,val){
            if($(val).val().length<=0)
            {
               alert ("Please fill all the fileds");

            }

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

See How it should wrap up

```
var x = $("input[name='"+value+"[]']")
```